# Converting from Geography to Geometry data type in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

I have a shapefile that has geography types.

Can I convert it with a tool like shp2pgsql or is there a postgis function to do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can cast the geography type to geometry by appending the `::geometry`

```
SELECT ST_Distance('LINESTRING(-122.33 47.606, 0.0 51.5)'::geometry, 'POINT(-21.96 64.15)'::geometry);
```

Answer (score 2):

shp2pgsql has a flag to import data in a geography type column:

```
shp2pgsql -G ....
```

But you can also import your data without it, by default shp2pgsql will create a geometry type.